# Using Log4j2 to reduce Java stack trace logging

Tags: java, stack-trace

I'd like Log4j2 to output a complete Java stack trace only once when an exception is first raised and not repeat that information as exceptions are propagated up the call chain.  I'm trying to figure out what custom Log4j2 components would implement this minimal call chain logging strategy.

I'm creating a custom layout based on *PatternLayout* and wondering if I need to create my own *PatternSelector*.  Before I get too far down this path, I'd love advice from those that understand the internals of Log4j2 (v2.13.3).

The following pseudocode illustrates the problem.

```
    m0() {try {m1();} catch (Exception e) {log.error("emsg0", e);} }
    m1() {try {m2();} catch (Exception e) {log.error("msg1", e); throw new Exception("emsg1", e);} }
    m2() {try {m3();} catch (Exception e) {log.error("msg2", e); throw new Exception("emsg2", e);} }
    m3() {_log.error("msg3"); throw new Exception("emsg3"); }
```

Here are the log records when the real code runs:

```
14:08:47.425 [main] ERROR edu.utexas.tacc.log4j2.Log4j2TestA - msg3
14:08:47.426 [main] ERROR edu.utexas.tacc.log4j2.Log4j2TestA - msg2
java.lang.Exception: emsg3
    at edu.utexas.tacc.log4j2.Log4j2TestA.m3(Log4j2TestA.java:24)
    at edu.utexas.tacc.log4j2.Log4j2TestA.m2(Log4j2TestA.java:22)
    at edu.utexas.tacc.log4j2.Log4j2TestA.m1(Log4j2TestA.java:19)
    at edu.utexas.tacc.log4j2.Log4j2TestA.m0(Log4j2TestA.java:17)
    at edu.utexas.tacc.log4j2.Log4j2TestA.main(Log4j2TestA.java:14)
14:08:47.431 [main] ERROR edu.utexas.tacc.log4j2.Log4j2TestA - msg1
java.lang.Exception: emsg2
    at edu.utexas.tacc.log4j2.Log4j2TestA.m2(Log4j2TestA.java:23)
    at edu.utexas.tacc.log4j2.Log4j2TestA.m1(Log4j2TestA.java:19)
    at edu.utexas.tacc.log4j2.Log4j2TestA.m0(Log4j2TestA.java:17)
    at edu.utexas.tacc.log4j2.Log4j2TestA.main(Log4j2TestA.java:14)
Caused by: java.lang.Exception: emsg3
    at edu.utexas.tacc.log4j2.Log4j2TestA.m3(Log4j2TestA.java:24)
    at edu.utexas.tacc.log4j2.Log4j2TestA.m2(Log4j2TestA.java:22)
    ... 3 more
14:08:47.432 [main] ERROR edu.utexas.tacc.log4j2.Log4j2TestA - msg0
java.lang.Exception: emsg1
    at edu.utexas.tacc.log4j2.Log4j2TestA.m1(Log4j2TestA.java:20)
    at edu.utexas.tacc.log4j2.Log4j2TestA.m0(Log4j2TestA.java:17)
    at edu.utexas.tacc.log4j2.Log4j2TestA.main(Log4j2TestA.java:14)
Caused by: java.lang.Exception: emsg2
    at edu.utexas.tacc.log4j2.Log4j2TestA.m2(Log4j2TestA.java:23)
    at edu.utexas.tacc.log4j2.Log4j2TestA.m1(Log4j2TestA.java:19)
    ... 2 more
Caused by: java.lang.Exception: emsg3
    at edu.utexas.tacc.log4j2.Log4j2TestA.m3(Log4j2TestA.java:24)
    at edu.utexas.tacc.log4j2.Log4j2TestA.m2(Log4j2TestA.java:22)
    at edu.utexas.tacc.log4j2.Log4j2TestA.m1(Log4j2TestA.java:19)
    ... 2 more
```

Here's what I'd rather see:

```
14:08:47.425 [main] ERROR edu.utexas.tacc.log4j2.Log4j2TestA - msg3
14:08:47.426 [main] ERROR edu.utexas.tacc.log4j2.Log4j2TestA - msg2
java.lang.Exception: emsg3
    at edu.utexas.tacc.log4j2.Log4j2TestA.m3(Log4j2TestA.java:24)
    at edu.utexas.tacc.log4j2.Log4j2TestA.m2(Log4j2TestA.java:22)
    at edu.utexas.tacc.log4j2.Log4j2TestA.m1(Log4j2TestA.java:19)
    at edu.utexas.tacc.log4j2.Log4j2TestA.m0(Log4j2TestA.java:17)
    at edu.utexas.tacc.log4j2.Log4j2TestA.main(Log4j2TestA.java:14)
14:08:47.431 [main] ERROR edu.utexas.tacc.log4j2.Log4j2TestA - msg1
    java.lang.Exception: emsg2
    Caused by: java.lang.Exception: emsg3
14:08:47.432 [main] ERROR edu.utexas.tacc.log4j2.Log4j2TestA - msg0
    java.lang.Exception: emsg1
    Caused by: java.lang.Exception: emsg2
    Caused by: java.lang.Exception: emsg3
```

Any guidance is appreciated,
Rich

Comment: This isn’t a log4j problem. Don’t catch these until they get to a central exception handler, then log them in one spot.

Comment: This doesn't exist today but you'd need to create a cache of previous exceptions to compare the new exception to.  And then it would be a memory issue - how long do you hold on to the "old" exceptions?  How many do you keep?

Comment: generally, in a given method, either log or throw the error, but don't do both.

Comment: Sounds like you can just recurse on `Exception.cause` until you find the last one. This has nothing to do with Log4J, unless you create your own appender.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your great comments.  **Abhijit's** approach was the one I was planning to take to avoid the complexities pointed out by **stdunbar**.  But I think the simple and elegant solution is to take **njzk2's** advice and either log or throw an exception, but don't do both.  I got into the habit of doing both after inheriting a quarter million lines of code that often swallowed exceptions leaving no trace of many events.  This effectively achieves the log-once approach **Nathan** advocated.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to create a custom ThrowablePatternConverter. But doing this probably isn't a good idea. In real life where apps run for a long time (days, weeks, or months) you might not see the exception for long periods of time and only seeing a 1 line caused by might get a bit frustrating since the root caused by exception is typically the most interesting one.
In addition, caching the exceptions and trying to do matching would make processing the exceptions pretty slow.

Comment: Agreed, keeping exceptions around for matching purposes probably creates more problems than it solves.  I find picking which Log4j2 extension point to focus on requires a fair amount of knowledge about Log4j2's internals.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution to this problem is to take njzk2's advice and either log or throw an exception, but don't do both.  As long as the code is reasonably well structured, each exception will get logged exactly once and Log4j2 will record the complete exception chain in an acceptable way.